# Android: E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting; android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column

Tags: android, sqlite

friends!
 I`m trying to fill a simple database from xml file, but receive an error in the title, and as written in log, the values in columns are placed in wrong order.

I can`t understand, where the problem is, so I ask for your help. The code is below.
Many thanks.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cards>
    <record path="R.mipmap.ot1"  woman = "wfew" man = "qwe"/>
    <record path="R.mipmap.ot2"  woman = "rewr" man = "dwd"/>
</cards>
```

DBhelper class:

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");

        db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "path text,"
                + "woman text," + "man text" + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Adding data to database:

```
 Resources res = this.getResources();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    XmlResourceParser _xml = res.getXml(R.xml.cardslist);
    try {

        int eventType = _xml.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    && (_xml.getName().equals("record"))) {

                String path = _xml.getAttributeValue(0);
                String woman = _xml.getAttributeValue(1);
                String man = _xml.getAttributeValue(2);
                values.put("path", path);
                values.put("woman", woman);
                values.put("man", man);
                db.insert("mytable", null, values);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "success");
            }
            eventType = _xml.next();
        }
    }
    // Catch errors
    catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e("Test", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Test", e.getMessage(), e);

    } finally {
        // Close the xml file
        _xml.close();
    }



    dbHelper.close();
}
```

Error from log:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table mytable has no column named man
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting path=dwd woman=R.mipmap.ot2 man=rewr
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mytable has no column named man (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mytable(path,woman,man) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Comment: have you had a fresh install of the app after adding the code? onCreate is only called on fresh install of app

Comment: Try deleting the App's data or uninstalling the App and then rerunning the App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add **`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`**
- Remove Multiple **`;`**

Try this way, Just Rectify your [**`execSQL`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) Statement.

```
 String sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, path TEXT, woman TEXT, man TEXT)";
  db.execSQL(sqlStatement);
```

**NOTE**

If the same problem coming then you need to modify

```
   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // ALTER TABLE LOGIC
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone, but now the data is inserted like path=qwe man=wfew woman=R.mipmap.ot1. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: @Sopelus `Is it possible to fix it?` sure. You should debug your app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall your app and then install it again because probabelly you changed the database schema and in your `onUpgrade` you don't increase the version number, take a look at [this link](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade) to understand what to do when you changed the schema